# WCF can return single object just fine but fails when returning a list

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, web

I've sent various other objects over my WCF service through lists without any issues however when I try to send this specific object (in a list) I get, sort of a timeout error.

The trace identifier is:
TraceIdentifier http://msdn.microsoft.com/da-DK/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceTruncatedQuotaExceeded.aspx

The strange thing is: I got another method that returns the object exclusively (not in a list) and it works fine.

Furthermore when debugging I've found out that the method (on the service side) returns the list just fine however it's the client that apparently fails receiving it.

Here's the method that calls the service (it fails on the line declaring "revs"):

```
public void GetReviewsInModule()
        {
            using (var db = new RentItServiceClient())
            {
                var revs = db.GetReviewsInModule(1);
            }
        }
```

Here's the method that actually returns the objectas a list (debugged it and it returns it fine):

```
public List<ReviewModule> GetReviewsInModule(int id)
    {
        using (Context con = new Context())
        {
            con.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            var mod = con.Modules.Find(id);
            if (mod == null)
                throw new WebServiceValidationException("Object does not exist");
            List<ReviewModule> revs = con.ModuleReviews.Include("User").Where(r => r.Module.Id == id).ToList();
            return revs;
        }
    }
```

Also, the object in the list are hardly of any size so please don't tell me to up the sending/receiving limits/timeouts.

Comment: I gave up on SOAP a long time ago and moved to REST and just moved a json object around - is there a specific reason for using a SOAP service? Also, check the WSDL to see if there is the object in there, or at least a link in there - you're looking for an xsd as SOAP uses XML

Comment: That link points to the danish mutation of msdn and doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give you an answer based just on the code you've posted, since it's not possible to replicate the problem just from those few snippets. (You'd need to post the full definition of ReviewModule, your service contract, etc, for that).

Therefore this is just a guess, but I've been caught out a few times when using WCF and MVC Web Api to set up RESTful web services when I've employed a Using block within endpoints. Although Using is a valuable construct within C#, I find that when you have one that's defined within a method that represents an endpoint that is ultimately called by code you don't control, then the IDisposable interface that the Using block relies on to work gets messed up. That is, you're defining an object within your method (in this case an object of type Context named "con"), and it's only later on that the WCF framework you're relying upon tries to access the object created within your endpoint. By the time the WCF framework does its job, the Dispose() method on your Context object is likely to already have been called by your code, meaning that the WCF framework can't access it in the way that it needs to in order to be able to return the data your service is intended to serve up. This may be the case even if your method works in isolation when you unit test it from code that is completely under your control.

To see if that's the problem in your case, try removing the Using block in your "GetReviewsInModule" method / service endpoint, like so:

```
public List<ReviewModule> GetReviewsInModule(int id)
{
    Context con = new Context();
    con.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    var mod = con.Modules.Find(id);
    if (mod == null) throw new WebServiceValidationException("Object does not exist");
    List<ReviewModule> revs = con.ModuleReviews.Include("User").Where(r => r.Module.Id == id).ToList();
    return revs;
}
```

If that causes your endpoint to start working as expected, you can worry about how you're going to manage object disposal and avoid memory leaks as a separate issue.

Comment: Huh? The list is created, the Context object is disposed and the list is serialized and returned to the client, what's supposed to be the problem?

Comment: I'm just saying what I've seen, and suggesting a possible cause of the problem in the face of an ambiguous problem description that doesn't allow readers to replicate the issue. The WCF and MVC Web Api frameworks sometimes have trouble accessing objects defined in Using blocks in user-defined code. Both frameworks are also guilty of not reporting what the problem is.

Comment: I know what you're doing, I'm just asking whether it makes any sense. A using block is nothing but a shorthand for calling Dispose() on an object when the execution leaves the block. In this case, since the revs object is initialized when this happens, how would the Dispose() call cause the timeout?

Comment: PS: The serialisation that you mentioned only happens later, within the WCF framework. Not within the endpoint itself. The WCF framework needs to be able to access the object of type List<Review> that is referenced by the revs variable in the above code to be able to serialise the result. That's where the problem seems to occur in issues I've seen. When/if the OP tries the suggested approach, he'll know for sure whether that's the problem in his case.

Comment: I've tried the above code but it still gave the same error.
The fact is that the method produces a list just fine however it's not being received correctly in the calling method.

Comment: Sorry my suggestion didn't help. If you can post a fully-working example of code that produces the error, that'll make it possible to analyse the problem and perhaps lead to a solution.

Comment: Since you're using streaming services (as you mentioned in your comment to my answer), the result of the method can only be a stream.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how many elements are in the result list, too, not only on the sizes of the individual elements. There are some configuration elements you can play with:

```
maxReceivedMessageSize
maxBufferSize
maxBufferPoolSize
maxArrayLength
maxStringContentLength
```

Another solution would be to switch to streamed WCF services. Please note that you can not mix streamed and buffered operations - I sometimes actually create two WCF services, one for streamed operations and one for buffered operations.

Comment: Well it fails even when only 1 element in the list.
Also we're already using streaming Wcf.

Comment: Impossible. Otherwise you service would have to return `Stream`, not `List<...>`, as a streamed service can only return streams and take streams as parameters.