# WCF Service not returning collection in web application

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding, wcf-security

My WCF service is hosted on local IIS. I could not get the result from the wcf call when I call it from the application. But it is strange that it is showing correct result in debugging(while step into the service classes) and returning array of object in the staging classes. and when debugging comes to the application it returns empty array. I have below call from application.

```
    public List<SurveyQuestion> GetCommonQuestionsForCompentency()
    {
        List<SurveyQuestion> questions = new List<SurveyQuestion>();
        SurveyQuestion[] ques = null;
        ICSSService.SurveyServiceClient client = null;
        try
        {
            client = (SurveyServiceClient)WCFSecurityEntityForSurvey.getSurveyClient();
            ques = client.GetCommonQuestionsByCategoryType(2);
            questions = ques.ToList<SurveyQuestion>();
            return questions;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally{ client.Close();}
    }
```

Call in the wcf service class shown below

[image]

Whats going wrong with the implementation. Any help?

**EDIT :**

It is working for a simple service call without list. I think the problem may be in the returning of collection. I found the similar questions [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730003/wcf-can-return-single-object-just-fine-but-fails-when-returning-a-list). But did not get much from this.

Comment: at the time of debugging did you check the variable in the immediate window or quick view window ? Also check whether the debugging mode of the application is on and it is not in release mode.(Configuration Manager)

Comment: yes there is tag ` <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />` in web.config

Comment: the issue is with the number of rows it returns. I had that exact issue once. try to restrict the query to a certain number of rows and then try.. like rownum < 1000 .. this helped in my case. and obviously it is not correct way of implementation but it will give you a clear vision that whether this is happening due to the data that the query is returning or not. Please try and let me know.

Comment: It gives me only 12 rows. It not be the data problem

Comment: I see.. did you check whether oncompleted function of that proxy function is firing or not.

Comment: Does the SurveyQuestion class have the DataContract attribute? If not then it is probably not getting serialized.

Comment: @Andy Nichols : Yes it is properly given.

Comment: @Ons : Where did oncompleted method is exist I do not found in the proxy.

Comment: check the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have similar problem with this.This is because References are not added correctly and I modified reference.cs file. So data is not gaining correctly if namespaces are different in the application. Just check the namespaces in your application. See if one of the class in your application have different namespace than others

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add a completed function and then add the grid data source to that.

in the page load add

```
AddHandler client.GetEndorsementCompleted, AddressOf GetEndorsement
```

then add the following function to let the async function hit.

> Private Sub GetEndorsement(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
>   SR.GetEndorsementCompletedEventArgs)
>           If Not e.Result.Equals(Nothing) Then
>
> ```
>      'Data grid binding
>
>     End If
> End Sub
> ```

In case of c# you can using this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37393/4-Simple-Steps-to-Consume-WCF-Service-using-Silver#Step%204%3a-%20Add%20the%20WCF%20service%20reference%20and%20call%20the%20service) from code project that demonstrate